# Jquery Toggle() Safari issue

Tags: jquery, safari

I am having a strange problem which is only present in Safari browser. My DOM is quite complicated, I tried to create a Jsfiddle but I messed everything up so I would like to ask someone to login to my website if that's possible. I would be very grateful.

Link: http://www.Lynxapp.io

Username: demo@demo.com

Password: demo

After you click 'Test Subject 1' or 'Test subject 2' in Chrome, Opera or even lastest IE, the children elements `toggle()` nicely. In Safari they also toggle, but the DOM isn't 'moved down' for some reason - in other words, the child elements just show up, but the elements at the bottom doesn't slide down nicely.

This is the code that Toggles the elements:

```
$(".small").children(".topics").hide()


$(".small").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".topics").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"});
});
```

I know that this is a simple issue, but I don't even know where should I start debugging from, because this feature works perfectly in other browsers (except Safari).

And sorry again for not creating Jsfiddle, but my DOM is kinda messy, so I was unsuccessfull at creating a good looking, working example at Jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari is respecting the height of the parent (in this case, your buttons with `.small`) which is 40px. So when you toggle something open inside these, it is not increasing the parent beyond 40px. And as such, the parent container `.subject` does not increase in size. To see what I mean, change your css for `.small` to this :

```
.small{
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: .5em;
}
```

This is not quite the effect you are looking for, but to get this to work in Safari you may need to consider moving the `.topics` divs outside of the `.small` buttons so that they are siblings.

Something like this :

```
<div class="custom_button white small"></div>
<div class="topics"></div>
<div class="custom_button white small"></div>
<div class="topics"></div>
```

And your jQuery :

```
$(".small").next(".topics").hide()

$(".small").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".topics").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"});
});
```

Comment: Sorry for answering so lately - the code worked fine as expected, now I just have to clean my DOM a little bit, thank you for your help :)